# Slow SQL Server 2008 R2 performance?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 on my development machine (not a server box).

I have a table with 12.5 million records. It has 126 columns, half of which are int. Most columns in most rows are NULL. I've also tested with an EAV design which seems 3-4 times faster to return the same records (but that means pivoting data to make it presentable in a table).

I have a website that paginates the data. When the user tries to go to the last page of records (last 25 records), the resulting query is something like this:

```
select * from (
  select 
    A.Id, part_id as PartObjectId, 
    Year_formatted 'year', Make_formatted 'Make',
    Model_formatted 'Model',
    row_number() over ( order by A.id ) as RowNum
  FROM vehicles A
) as innerQuery where innerQuery.RowNum between 775176 and 775200
```

... but this takes nearly 3 minutes to run. That seems excessive? Is there a better way to structure this query? In the browser front-end I'm using jqGrid to display the data. The user can navigate to the next, previous, first, or last page. They can also filter and order data (example: show all records whose Make is "Bugatti").

vehicles.Id is int and is the primary key (clustered ASC). part_id is int, Make and Model are varchar(100) and typically only contain 20 - 30 characters.

Table vehicles is updated ~100 times per day in individual transactions, and 20 - 30 users use the webpage to view, search, and edit/add vehicles 8 hours/day. It gets read from and updated a lot.

Would it be wise to shard the vehicles table into multiple tables only containing say 3 million records each? Would that have much impact on performance?

I see lots of videos and websites talking about people having tables with 100+ million rows that are read from and updated often without issue.

Note that the performance issues I observe are on my own development computer. The database has a dedicated 16GB of RAM. I'm not using SSD or even SCSI for that matter. So I know hardware would help, but 3 minutes to retrieve the last 25 records seems a bit excessive no?

Though I'm running these tests on SQL Server 2008 R2, I could also use 2012 if there is much to be gained from doing so.

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported database for such processing? SQL Server 2016 supports columnstore indexes and in-memory tables even in the Express edition. What you try to do now, is already available. You could get 1000 times improvement just by using in-memory tables and/or columnstores.

Comment: In general, I would highly recommend that you don't change a working database structure and working queries because of issues in your development environment that aren't occurring in production. Get explain plans for the query in both environments, and figure out what is different. This could be a config issue on your dev computer, a hardware issue, outdated stats - i.e. there are many potential causes. And something that performs well on your dev machine might actually perform poorly in production!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The client of the company I work for dictates the database we're bound too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a better way, even on older releases of MsSQL  But it is involved. First, this process should be done in a stored procedure.  The stored procedure should take as 2 of it's input parameters, the page requested (`@page`)and the page size (number of records per page - `@pgSiz`).

In the stored procedure,

Create a temporary table variable and put into it a sorted list of the integer Primary Keys for all the records, with a rowNumber column that is itself an indexed, integer, Primary Key for the temp table

```
 Declare @PKs table 
    (rowNo integer primary key Identity not null, 
     vehicleId integer not null)
 Insert @PKS (vehicleId)
 Select vehicleId from Vehicles
 Order By --[Here put sort criteria as you want pages sorted]
          --[Try to only include columns that are in an index]
```

then, based on which page (and the page size), (@page, @pgSiz) the user requested, the stored proc selects the actual data for that page by joining to this temp table variable:

```
 Select [The data columns you want]
 From @PKS p join Vehicles v
    on v.VehicleId = p.VehicleId 
 Where rowNo between @page*@pgSiz+1 and (@page+1)*@pgSiz 
 order by rowNo -- if you want to sort page of records on server
```

assuming `@page` is 0-based. Also, the Stored proc will need some input argument validation to ensure that the `@page`, `@pgSize` values are reasonable (do not take the code pas the end of the records.)

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Awesome! It took my query time from about 3 minutes down to 6 seconds! Thank you

Comment: Is my old way slow because internally when it sorts records it's making a copy of the data in each row as it sorts?

Comment: No it's because it's reading the entire table from disk. The way I described, it only needs to read the primary key column, and whatever columns you put in the order by, and they are likely in an index, which is much narrower, (fewer pages on disk). If all are in an index, then it may not have to read the actual table  itself to generate the table variable, just the index. Then when it actually fetches the one page of data, it is only reading data from disk for the records on that page.

Comment: It appers that the second query needs to sort by p.rowNo. If I do not, the second query (which joins PKs to Vehicles) does not return the vehicles in the same order in which they are stored in PKs.

Comment: if you want to do that on server, that's fine. That won't affect the performance of the process much, since there are only `pgSiz` rows there.